# How to use "HTTP authentication" in goaccess

Tags: nginx, ansible, nginx-config, goaccess

How to use "HTTP authentication" in goaccess. 
Im not able to understand this. Help me out here.

I am using this:

`sudo goaccess /var/log/nginx/access.log -o /var/www/html/report.html --log-format=COMBINED --real-time-html`

https://goaccess.io/man#description

Remote User (HTTP Authentication) This is the UserID of the person requesting the document as determined by HTTP Authentication. If the document is not password protected, this part will be "-" just like the previous one. This panel is not enabled unless %e is given within the log-format variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that goaccess doesn't have a auth system built-in, the HTML generated need to be protected by other means, there is some open issues also for WS auth, that is user for real time updates: https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/1133

The most easy solution is to use a reverse proxy with HTTP Authentication, the documentation says that you can use the '%e' placeholder to reference the user that was authenticated.